# On a Variational Inequality

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, calculus-of-variations, fixed-point-theorems

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with real inner product. Consider $f: C \rightarrow C$, where $C \subset H$ is closed and convex.

I am not sure about the variational inequality problem: find $x \in H$ s.t.
$$ \langle f(x) - x, \ J(x-y) \rangle \geq 0$$
for all $y \in K \subset C \subset H$, where $J$ is the dual mapping.

How does this problem look like if $H = \mathbb{R}^n$?

Now assume that $f$ is decreasing (hence pseudocontractive, i.e., $\text{Id} - f$ is monotone).

Are there computational (iterative) methods to solve the variational inequality (say for $H = \mathbb{R}^n$)?

Comment: What exactly is your question? And what is the relation of $K$ to $C$?

Comment: $K \subset C$. My question is about the case $H = \mathbb{R}^n$. 1. How does the VI becomes (eliminating $J$). 2. How to solve it (when $f$ is pseudocontractive).

Comment: Before starting to calculate, you should ensure that the problem has a solution. Under these conditions, you will have some trouble. Is $C$ bounded? Do you have any boundedness or coercivity condition for $f$?